# Show that group $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_3$.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, permutation-cycles

I have this question:

Let $w = e^{\frac{2 \pi i}{3}}$, that is $w^3 = 1$ and $G = {w^0, w^1, w^2}$ or $G = {1,\frac{\frac{-1}{2} + i \sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\frac{-1}{2} - i \sqrt{3}}{2}}$. Show that $G$ is $\mathbb{Z}_3$ isomorphic.

I set up Cayley's table for the two groups, but I can't see or justify why the two are isomorphic.

I saw that the two groups maintain the same cyclicality, but is that enough to say that they are isomorphic?

Thanks.

Comment: all groups with prime number order are isomorphic/cyclic

Comment: Find a bijective mapping $m$ from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to $G$ such that $m(a+b) = m(a)m(b)$.

Comment: an isomorphism maps the identity to the identity

Comment: These comments are all correct and potentially helpful, but this problem is extremely easy once you're comfortable with the relevant concepts, so it's most likely that you need help engraining the idea of an isomorphism. What does "isomorphism" mean for you? If someone claimed that these two groups are isomorphic, what would they have to do to convince you they're right?

Comment: Now I get it.. 
Thank you people!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The elements $w^0, w^1, w^2$ correspond to the vertices of a triangle in the complex plane. Multiplication by $w^1$ permutes these vertices cyclically.

Addition of $[1]_3$ in $\Bbb Z_3$ permutes the elements of $\Bbb Z_3$ cyclically too.